# Grunt / NPM Uglify doesn't like this JS line

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

When I run `grunt build` Uglify fails here:

`yz = d3.range(n).map(function() { return k.map(x => x[1]); }),`

The error says:

`Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: operator (>).`

I've just recently started seeing this `=>` syntax in JS and don't use it myself (this use case is from a suggestion)... Is there another way to handle the faulty statement? or upgrade from `"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0"` ?

Comment: I don't see `k` defined on the first `map`...  Also, is your grunt build cool with the es6 fat-arrows?  Or have you not set that up yet?

Comment: haven't set that up yet. I'd rather try to update to handle this instead of changing the code itself

Comment: Yeah, so if that's the case then you _probably_ can just convert the ES6 syntax to ES5 syntax and write the inner `map` as `function (x) { return x[1]; }` (instead of `x => x[1]`).

Answer (score 3):

`=>` is ES6 [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es with it.
You can use the [harmony branch of grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/tree/harmony) which uses `uglify-es`.